# How to correctly install RVM in Docker?

Tags: ruby, bash, docker, rvm

This is what I have in my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
RUN curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm requirements"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install 2.3.3"
```

Works just fine, however, when I start the container, I see this:

```
$ docker -it --rm myimage /bin/bash
/root# ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
/root# /bin/bash -l -c "ruby --version"
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
```

Obviously, this is not what I want. As far as I understand, the problem is that `bash` doesn't run `/etc/profile` by default. That's why Ruby is not coming from the RVM installation. How can I fix that?

Comment: question for you: why use rvm inside of a docker container? in my experience docker makes rvm obsolete. you stand up a new container for each ruby version you need. there's probably something i'm missing, though, and i'd be curious to know why you're using rvm in docker.

Comment: Good question. This is a general purpose Docker image, which is used by many projects. Each project must have an ability to use its own Ruby version, by just saying `rvm install 2.1.0`, without the necessity to create its own Docker image. All this happens in www.rultor.com project.

Comment: interesting.... in that scenario, i would create a base image that contains everything you need before you pick the specific ruby version. from there, create additional dockerfiles that inherit `FROM` from your base image and install the specific ruby version required. no rvm needed. of course, i'm dramatically oversimplifying the situation. might not be that easy in real life :)

Comment: Your scenario is more in the spirit of Docker, but will require more steps for our users. Now, it's just a matter of saying `rvm install 2.1.0` in [`.rultor.yml`](http://doc.rultor.com/reference.html) and you have Ruby 2.1.0. No Docker knowledge required.

Comment: that's certainly a great goal! i'm doing the same for another project with Node.js v7 - simplifying it so no one has to know anything about docker.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Long story short:

`docker -it --rm myimage /bin/bash` command does not start bash as a login shell.

Explanation:

When you run `$ docker -it --rm myimage /bin/bash` it's invoke bash without the `-l` option which make `bash` act as if it had been invoked as a login shell, `rvm` initializations depends on the `source`-ing `/path/to/.rvm/scripts/rvm` or `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` and that initialization is in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or any other initialization scripts.

> How can I fix that?

If you won't, always have the `ruby` from `rvm` add `-l` option.

Here is a Dockerfile with installed `ruby` by `rvm`:

```
FROM Debian

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -qy procps curl ca-certificates gnupg2 build-essential --no-install-recommends && apt-get clean

RUN gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
RUN /bin/bash -l -c ". /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm install 2.3.3"
# The entry point here is an initialization process, 
# it will be used as arguments for e.g.
# `docker run` command 
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
```

Run the container:

```
➠ docker_templates : docker run -ti --rm rvm 'ruby -v'
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
➠ docker_templates : docker run -ti --rm rvm 'rvm -v'
rvm 1.29.1 (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]
➠ docker_templates : docker run -ti --rm rvm bash
root@efa1bf7cec62:/# rvm -v
rvm 1.29.1 (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]
root@efa1bf7cec62:/# ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
root@efa1bf7cec62:/#
```

Comment: Can you please show how exactly I have to change my `Dockerfile` so that every time I run `docker /bin/bash` Ruby version is 2.3.3?

Comment: The only one thing I can imagine is make the  initialization in the `ENTRYPOINT`  option(or `CMD`, or point `CMD` to a little shell script which does initialization), something like this `[[ -s "/path_to_rvm/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/path_to_rvm/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && /bin/bash`, that's should first check the rvm script, second `source` that script and load `bash` shell. _Note about `/path_to_rvm`_!

Comment: Would be great if you just post your version of `Dockerfile` into your answer, will be convenient for others too. Thanks!

Comment: Trying to make a container with ruby installed trough `rvm`, to confirm my answer.

Comment: @Зелёный please consider marking Alev his answer as the correct one. It's more clear.

Comment: I didn't have the binary in above location, but was able to run it via `RUN .rvm/bin/rvm install 3.1.3`

Answer (score 28):

Don't use `RUN bash -l -c rvm install 2.3.3`. It's very scruffy. You can set shell command by `SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" ]` and simply call `RUN rvm install 2.3.3`.

Comment: Nice. This command also solves a lot of future issues related with "command not found" errors.

Comment: This is really the best answer!