# Redmine & rake version: how to update for user redmine

Tags: docker, rake, redmine

I need to update rake to version 12.2.1
I am using a Redmine docker image. So I tried to add to Gemfile the following line:

**gem "rake", "12.2.1"**

When I connect to my docker container running redmine, only under root user I see the updated version of rake, but as redmine user I see the older version, as shown by the following commands:

```
root# rake --version
rake, version 12.2.1

root# su - redmine
redmine$ rake --version
rake, version 10.4.2
```

I am not so confident with ruby and redmine, so I'm asking for any useful suggestions.

Thank you in advance.
Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install your rake and ruby via rvm under redmine user, reffer to this question on stackoverflow [How to correctly install RVM in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612927/how-to-correctly-install-rvm-in-docker)

And once you are done with RVM, re-run `bundle install` for Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

Already installed gems can be updated by using

```
bundle update <gemname>
```

doing that also  make sure you are the right user (probably `redmine` in your case) and in the right path (e.g. the root of your Redmine)