# How to execute shell command from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, nginx, passenger

I am facing a issue when tried to run shell command from rails controller.
Tried in 3 different environments

1. Local (Puma)
2. Staging Server( standalone passenger)
3. Live (Nginx + Passenger 5.3.4)

Ruby installed in live directly by source (no rvm and rbenv)

It is working in Local and Sandbox but `127` error in live

Tried with below 4 ways but all these are woking only in Local and Sandbox not on live

```
  def enable_sidekiq
    system 'bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production'
    exec('bundle sidekiq -d -e production') #working but stops rail console
    %x{bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production}
    `bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production`
    puts $?  # this shows - pid 23543 exit 0 (when successfull)
    # this shows - pid 23456 exit 127 (when  not successfull)
  end
```

Error:

```
Passenger AppPreloader: /path/to/project (forking...): No such file or directory - bundle
```

Comment: You should use `rvm and rbenv`, because `bundler` depends on rubygems(finds, loads and runs gems). Its a little tricky since rvm and rbenv behave differently in the defferent shells.

Comment: I would never recommend starting Sidekiq by starting a new process from your existing Rails app (and definitely would not recommend starting it from a controller action!) I suggest reading [the wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment) to understand how to start Sidekiq properly.

Comment: @Зелёный I would never recommend using RVM or rbenv in a production environment. Docker, for example, does not play very well with them.

Comment: @anothermh [rvm works in docker very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612927/how-to-correctly-install-rvm-in-docker/43613426#43613426).

Comment: @parul-kanani Yes, do not start sidekiq from a controller or by forking another process. Also, it doesn't matter if RVM/rbenv play well with docker or not. It is not the best way. If you are using docker, then use supervisor to do so. If you aren't using docker, use your host's/host os's service manager to start it.

Comment: @anothermh Yes, you are right. It's not good to use that in controller but my sidekiq stopped randomly in my live server so I think this way is last option to me. Let me know if you have better way to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Зелёный I installed ruby from ruby source so is it not possible to do with this ?
I have issue of sidekiq because it's stop working randomly so I want to start it whenever it's stop. I will be great if you have any better idea to resolve this.

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari I am not using docker. What is your suggestion for this?

Comment: @ParulKanani use `systemd` in order to run and restart `sidekiq`.

Comment: @Зелёный Are you talking about this? https://gist.github.com/mkhuda/132787f9d54890a183d665eb4560f196

Comment: @ParulKanani yes.

Comment: @Зелёный Do it work for ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @ParulKanani my bad, Ubuntu 14.10 and below use upstart.

Comment: @Зелёный I think for this RVM or rbenv is required

Comment: You should be running Sidekiq _separately_ from your Rails server. If Sidekiq is shutting down unexpectedly then _fix that problem_, do not try to solve it by doing the wrong thing and running it as a forked process from your Rails server. It's unclear how you're running them, but if for example you're using Docker then you would start two separate Docker containers. They can be identical Docker images, but they would use different `CMD` actions: `bundle exec rails server` and `bundle exec sidekiq`. This question is a perfect example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @anothermh I am not using Docker. I used AWS, load balancer. I think due to heavy load sidekiq stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: @anothermh, I used this command `bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production` to start sidekiq

Comment: Why is Sidekiq running behind a load balancer? That's not how Sidekiq works. You push jobs to Sidekiq via Redis, and the Sidekiq server reads the jobs from Redis. Besides that, Sidekiq will not exit under heavy load. I've run Sidekiq with millions of jobs per day doing CPU-intensive work; if it exits, it exits for a reason listed in the logs.

Comment: @anothermh Yes it's work via redis only.

Comment: I want to emphasize again that you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), that the question you've asked is the wrong question and not representative of the real problem. Check your Sidekiq logs and if you're unsure why it's terminating then open a question about that instead. And carefully read the Sidekiq [wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/) to make sure you fully understand the Sidekiq architecture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186031/discussion-between-parul-kanani-and-anothermh).