# ubuntu container install rvm failing

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install rvm in ubuntu docker image with following dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -qy procps curl ca-certificates gnupg2 build-essential --no-install-recommends && apt-get clean

RUN curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -
RUN curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -

RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

RUN . /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

RUN rvm install 1.9.3-dev
```

But at last command I get

```
Step 8/9 : RUN rvm install 1.9.3-dev
 ---> Running in 1b1c6454868d
/bin/sh: 1: rvm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c rvm install 1.9.3-dev' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

An idea what's wrong here ?

Comment: You usually don't need version-manager tools like `rvm` in Docker, since an image is already an isolated filesystem that runs a single application.  Just install the version of Ruby you need as the "system" Ruby, or use the Docker Hub `ruby` image as your base.  (1.9.3 is rather dated, though.)

Comment: Yes, and better yet, you can use the [official Ruby Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `. /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` does not persist into the next `RUN` layer. That shell file modifies a few things, like the `PATH` variable, and without it, `rvm` will not be found in `PATH`. You can source it and run `rvm` in the same layer.

```
RUN bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm install 1.9.3-dev"
```

Also, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43613426/5666087) regarding rvm in Docker.